# board game previous sum value store

Tags: java, android

> hello i am making one board game .in that i getting one dice value and
>   i adding to one variable . but before rolling dice i want to store
>   pervious turn value  into one varible. can anybody suggest how to do
>   that??
>
> i am doing like this way but its not giving me success.
>
> on dice click event

```
 public static int sum = 0;
public static int lastvalue = 0;
int[] rollingnumber = new int[48];
                    lastvalue++;
                    sum = sum + gs.getImagelevel();
                    gs.setLastsum(sum);
                    for (int i = 0; i < lastvalue; i++)
                    {
                        rollingnumber[i] = gs.getLastsum();
                        Log.i("hello", "i :: " + i + "array :: " + rollingnumber[i]
                                + "lastvalue :: " + lastvalue);
                    }
```

Comment: "before rolling dice i want to store pervious turn value into one variable" - you are not able to do that? why?

Comment: becuase i have 2 players and only one dice

Comment: well this is tricky -- will multiple people play the game at a given instance .. static will be a bad idea in that case -

Comment: Cant you have as many previous-turn-value variables as the number of players?

Comment: if you have solution please let me know

Comment: that is very much tedious way take as many turn variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
                lastvalue++;
                sum = sum + gs.getImagelevel();
                rollingnumber[lastvalue] += sum;
                for (int i = 0; i < lastvalue; i++)
                {
                    Log.i("hello", "i :: " + i + "array :: " + rollingnumber[i]
                            + "   lastvalue :: " + lastvalue);
                }
```

> i have done by this way , and for another player its also working